# How could I make a picturebox to become like a platform that my player can jump into?

Tags: c#, winforms

I already have a player movement and jump using timer control with 1ms interval, and my problem is that I can't make a picture box to become a platform, here's my code of my character movement

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    bool left, right;
    bool jump;
    int G = 20;
    int Force;


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right) { right = true; }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left) { left = true; }

        if (jump != true)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
            {
                jump = true;
                Force = G;
            }
        }
    }

    private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right) { right = false; }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left) { left = false; }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (right == true) { player.Left += 5; }
        if (left == true) { player.Left -= 5; }

        if (jump == true)
        {
            //Falling (if the player has jumped before)
            player.Top -= Force;
            Force -= 1;
        }

        if (player.Top + player.Height >= screen.Height)
        {
            player.Top = screen.Height - player.Height; //Stop falling at bottom
            jump = false;
        }
        else
        {
            player.Top += 5;//Falling 
        } 
    }
}
```

I'm using winforms to create this game, because that's what is required.

Comment: There is nothing resembling a "platform" in this snippet.  Consider that a platform moves a player object, it is no longer the keys that do it.  Write your code accordingly.

Comment: Look at my edited answer

Comment: How did you achieved 1msec interval?? I am very curious. What you say as 1msec is in fact 16msec!

Comment: I just edited the timer control's property , interval to 1

Comment: As i said. Winform `timer` doesn't have so low increment. The best is 16. So, you set it to 1 but in reality you got 16 which is ~60fps at **best**.

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't know that, thanks for clarifying, pardon me for being super noob in this :)

Comment: Can you evaluate on *picture box to become a platform* a little more? I can't understand what you mean.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know how to explain codes(because I'm really a super noob in codin), but only describe what I want to achieve. If my player collides to the top of the 2nd picture box, I want my player to be able to move at the top of the 2nd picture box

Comment: So you mean to move on top of the picbox not fall down?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean :)

Comment: Can you provide the `Player` class and how do you initialize it? It should be fairly easy to accomplish.

Comment: Uhmm, I think I don't have a Player class, I only have a picturebox named "player" and all of its movements are in my question... sorry :(

Comment: You can check my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Uh i guess it is some homework since you are making game in winforms so i will not write you code but tell you how does work flow goes.

Since you have movement part i will not explain that.

What you are looking for is `Colliding`. What does it mean is when two objects `fictional borders` collide, what to do (so when they touch themselves).

`Fictional borders` are called `Colliders` and what you need to do is create `collider` for your `player` and for some object. `Collider` can be one single object (square) or multiple objects (Multiple squares, circles....). For this example we will create `colliders` with simple squares since your game is 2d.

[image]

As you can see up we created collider for player (green one) and collider for object (yellow one).

As you can see players collider is colliding with objects collider. At the moment those two collide we raise event and do something.

That something has many solutions, some better than others, but two simple solution you could do is next thing:

- Apply opposite direction force
- Move to the previous location

Apply opposite direction force is complex thing and need for you to check where collider has been colliding and then move object to that direction (since you will not always stand on object but you could hit the wall for example) and it requires some code which is not suitable for beginner who is doing it just for practicing `winforms`.

Move to previous location is easy solution for you and would be done like this:

- Each 5ms you remember current players position
- Each 1ms you check if it collides with something
- If it collides you move him back on last remembered position.

Now you would ask why to remember each 5ms but not 1ms. It is because if something happen and collider doesn't detect colliding but it did collide, player will remember that position and when collide happens it will move back to last saved position but that one is already inside wall. This way we are reducing chances of that happening. Of course you test and see what suits you best. Also this example will create laggy movement but still, you will not make real game in there.

This is only easy solution for making this work but it is not recommended one.

If you want more complex and precise solutions there are a lot of articles on internet and i would suggest you to look at how `Unity 2d collision` works and translate that into your code.

Since i got interested in doing it in winforms i have also made it.

Here is code i used:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Game
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Player player;
        Obsticle obsticle;

        Thread UpdateThread;

        public const int Gravity = 1;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeObjects();

            UpdateThread = new Thread(() => {
                System.Timers.Timer UpdateTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
                UpdateTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(Update);
                UpdateTimer.Interval = 2;
                UpdateTimer.Enabled = true;                
            });
            UpdateThread.Start();
        }

        private void InitializeObjects()
        {
            PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
            pb.BackgroundImage = global::Game.Properties.Resources.SuperMario;
            pb.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
            pb.Location = new Point(47, 59);
            pb.Name = "Player";
            pb.Size = new Size(76, 72);
            pb.TabIndex = 0;
            pb.TabStop = false;
            player = new Player(this, pb);

            PictureBox pb1 = new PictureBox();
            pb1.BackgroundImage = global::Game.Properties.Resources.Box;
            pb1.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
            pb1.Location = new Point(47, 226);
            pb1.Name = "Obsticle";
            pb1.Size = new Size(100, 95);
            pb1.TabIndex = 0;
            pb1.TabStop = false;
            obsticle = new Obsticle(this, pb1);
        }
        private void Update(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            player.ApplyGravity(Gravity);
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);

            player.Collider.DrawCollider(e.Graphics);
            obsticle.Collider.DrawCollider(e.Graphics);
        }
    }

    public class Object
    {
        public static List<Object> Objects = new List<Object>();

        public Form Handler;
        public PictureBox Picture { get; set; }
        public BoxCollider Collider { get; set; }

        public int x
        {
            get
            {
                return _x;
            }
            set
            {
                _x = value;
                Handler.Invoke(new Action(() => {
                    Picture.Location = new Point((int)_x, Picture.Location.Y);
                    Handler.Refresh();
                }));
            }
        }
        public int y
        {
            get
            {
                return _y;
            }
            set
            {
                _y = value;
                Handler.Invoke(new Action(() => {
                    Picture.Location = new Point(Picture.Location.X, _y);
                    Handler.Refresh();
                }));
            }
        }

        private int _x;
        private int _y;

        public Object(Form handler, PictureBox Picture)
        {
            this.Handler = handler;
            this.Picture = Picture;

            _x = Picture.Location.X;
            _y = Picture.Location.Y;

            handler.Controls.Add(Picture);

            Collider = new BoxCollider(this);

            Objects.Add(this);
        }

        public void ApplyGravity(int gravityForce)
        {
            if (Collider.CheckCollide())
                return;
            y += gravityForce;
        }
    }
    public class Player : Object
    {
        public int movementSpeed { get { return _movementSpeed; } }
        private int _movementSpeed = 10;

        public Player(Form handler, PictureBox Picture) : base(handler, Picture)
        {
        }

        public void MoveDown(int value)
        {
            y += value;
        }
    }
    public class Obsticle : Object
    {
        public Obsticle(Form handler, PictureBox Picture) : base(handler, Picture)
        {
        }
    }

    public class BoxCollider
    {
        private Pen Pen_Default = new Pen(Color.Red);
        private Object Object;
        private Rectangle rect;

        public BoxCollider(Object Object)
        {
            this.Object = Object;
        }

        public bool CheckCollide()
        {
            foreach(Object o in Object.Objects)
            {
                if (rect.IntersectsWith(o.Collider.rect) && o.Collider.rect != rect)
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public void DrawCollider(Graphics g)
        {
            rect = new Rectangle(Object.Picture.Location.X, Object.Picture.Location.Y, Object.Picture.Width, Object.Picture.Height);
            Pen_Default.Width = 5;
            g.DrawRectangle(Pen_Default, rect);
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't have movement mechanism since i have only wanted to test collision. You will get error for resources if you copy/paste it so just add 2 images and test it out :)

Point in this code is that you before changing any position variable you need to call
    if (Collider.CheckCollide())
                return;
so when it collides it will not move object. Also you can implement `Collider` types so you tell some object collide with others (like power ups)

Answer (score 0):

You can check the code your self. I added 3 `pictureboxes` in my form. Just to simplifie matters the form is not maximized.

[image]

**Code:**

```
bool left, right;
bool jump;
int G = 20;
int Force;
List<Rectangle> obstacles = new List<Rectangle>();
```

Add `obstacles`:

```
public Form1() {
    InitializeComponent();

    obstacles.Add( new Rectangle( pictureBox1.Left, pictureBox1.Top, pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height ) );
    obstacles.Add( new Rectangle( pictureBox2.Left, pictureBox2.Top, pictureBox2.Width, pictureBox2.Height ) );
    obstacles.Add( new Rectangle( pictureBox3.Left, pictureBox3.Top, pictureBox3.Width, pictureBox3.Height ) );
    obstacles.Add( new Rectangle( -1, 0, 1, this.ClientSize.Height ) ); //left border of form
    obstacles.Add( new Rectangle( this.ClientSize.Width, 0, 1, this.ClientSize.Height ) ); //right border of form
    obstacles.Add( new Rectangle( 0, this.ClientSize.Height, this.ClientSize.Width, 1 ) ); //down border of form
    obstacles.Add( new Rectangle( 0, -1, this.ClientSize.Height, 1 ) ); //up border of form

}
```

and in `tick` event:

```
private void timer1_Tick( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
    Rectangle playerClone = player.Bounds; // new Rectangle( player.Left, player.Top, player.Width, player.Height );
    List<int> list = new List<int>();

    if( left == true ) {
        playerClone.X -= 5;

        //Check if we have left colision
        int pos = GetIntersectPosL( playerClone );

        if( pos >= 0 ) { //there is a colision
            playerClone.X = pos;
        }
    }
    else if( right == true ) {
        playerClone.X += 5;

        //Check if we have right colision
        int pos = GetIntersectPosR( playerClone );

        if( pos >= 0 ) { //there is a colision
            playerClone.X = pos - playerClone.Width;
        }
    }

    if( jump == true ) {
        playerClone.Y -= (Force - 5); //the 5 is from falling.

        if( Force - 5 >= 0 ) { //going up
            //Check if we have up colision, if the top of the player is colliding with anything
            int pos = GetIntersectPosU( playerClone );

            if( pos >= 0 ) { //there is a colision
                playerClone.Y = pos;
            }
        }
        else { //Falling down
            //Check if we have down colision, if the bottom of the player is colliding with anything
            int pos = GetIntersectPosD( playerClone );

            if( pos >= 0 ) { //there is a colision
                playerClone.Y = pos - playerClone.Height;

                jump = false;
            }
        }

        Force -= 1;
    }
    else { //Falling without previous jumping
        playerClone.Y += 5;

        //Check if we have down colision, if the bottom of the player is colliding with anything
        int pos = GetIntersectPosD( playerClone );

        if( pos >= 0 ) { //there is a colision
            playerClone.Y = pos - playerClone.Height;
        }

    }

    player.Bounds = playerClone;
}

private int GetIntersectPosL(Rectangle src) {
    List<int> list = new List<int>();

    //Get all intersect rectangles and add the right side to the list
    for( int i = 0; i < obstacles.Count; i++ ) {
        if( src.IntersectsWith( obstacles[ i ] ) == true ) {
            list.Add( obstacles[ i ].Right );
        }
    }

    if( list.Count == 0 ) { //no intersect
        return -1;
    }

    return list.Max();
}

private int GetIntersectPosR( Rectangle src ) {
    List<int> list = new List<int>();

    //Get all intersect rectangles and add the left side to the list
    for( int i = 0; i < obstacles.Count; i++ ) {
        if( src.IntersectsWith( obstacles[ i ] ) == true ) {
            list.Add( obstacles[ i ].Left );
        }
    }

    if( list.Count == 0 ) { //No intersect
        return -1;
    }

    return list.Min();
}

private int GetIntersectPosD( Rectangle src ) {
    List<int> list = new List<int>();

    //Get all intersect rectangles and add the top side to the list
    for( int i = 0; i < obstacles.Count; i++ ) {
        if( src.IntersectsWith( obstacles[ i ] ) == true ) {
            list.Add( obstacles[ i ].Top );
        }
    }

    if( list.Count == 0 ) { //No intersect
        return -1;
    }

    return list.Min();
}

private int GetIntersectPosU( Rectangle src ) {
    List<int> list = new List<int>();

    //Get all intersect rectangles and add the bottom side to the list
    for( int i = 0; i < obstacles.Count; i++ ) {
        if( src.IntersectsWith( obstacles[ i ] ) == true ) {
            list.Add( obstacles[ i ].Bottom );
        }
    }

    if( list.Count == 0 ) { //No intersect
        return -1;
    }

    return list.Max();
}
```